# Samba high cpu usage after mapping shares to windows network drive

Tags: centos, windows-7, samba

We moved our file server from Windows 2008R2 to CenotOS & Samba and did some tests. Everything worked fast and smooth so we decided to move for good. We mapped the share to network drive and then Samba server CPU usage jumped to 100%, even with only 10-15 users logged in.

All clients are Windows 7 / Windows 2008R2 SP1 HPC machines.

Answer (score 1):

Have you had a look at top, is it samba taking the IO?

Try having a look at `smbstatus` and log files, maybe a file has been locked and is causing samba to get stuck in a loop. It's quite common to have to turn `op locking off`. Some info about locking [here](http://oreilly.com/openbook/samba/book/ch05_05.html). I am guessing obviously, since it is hard to give a good answer with not much information.

Comment: Shares to Linux work OK, unfortunately windows downloads files 2-4x slower.